# ggplot barplot graph same size for different groups

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a barplot for three whale species of baleen whales along multiple months. My problem is that the size of the bars changes between months as there are months without no sighting of one of the species. Any idea how can I solve this?

I use this code:

```
land_based_individuals <- read.csv("Land_based_sightings_antero.csv", 
                                   header = T, sep =",", dec =",", stringsAsFactors = F)

land_based_individuals_month <- aggregate(land_based_individuals$sightings, 
                                          by = list(land_based_individuals$Month, land_based_individuals$Species), 
                                          FUN=sum)

colnames(land_based_sightings_month)[1] <- "Month"
colnames(land_based_sightings_month)[2] <- "Species"
colnames(land_based_sightings_month)[3] <- "Sightings"

library (ggplot2)

ggplot(land_based_sightings_month, 
       aes(fill=Species, y=Sightings, x=land_based_sightings_month$Month)) +  
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity") +
  ggtitle("Land-based Sightings per month")+ xlab("Month")+ ylab("Sightings")+  
  scale_x_continuous("Month", labels = as.character(land_based_sightings_month$Month), 
                     breaks = land_based_sightings_month$Month)+  
  ggsave(file="Land-based Sightings per month.png",  
         width = 14, height = 9, dpi = 120)
```

This is the barplot that I get from this [data](https://ethercalc.org/js0qj4oezttq)

[image]

Comment: This is the link to the data https://ethercalc.org/js0qj4oezttq. Thanks

Comment: I made an edit that puts the data in the qustion

Answer (score 2):

You can use `tidyr::complete` to complete missing `Month`-`Species` combinations with 0.

```
library(tidyverse)
land_based_individuals %>%
    group_by(Month, Species) %>%
    summarise(Sightings = sum(Sightings)) %>%
    complete(Month, Species, fill = list(Sightings = 0)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(Month, Sightings, fill = Species)) +
        geom_col(position = "dodge2") +
        ggtitle("Land-based Sightings per month") +
        xlab("Month") +
        ylab("Sightings")
```

[image]

I have also cleaned up your code which contained a few (minor) code and formatting issues. Most importantly, never use `$`-indexing inside `aes` in `ggplot`; this may lead to some nasty and unexpected results when using e.g. facets.